# Where are scheduled tasks stored in an offline windows 10 image?

Tags: windows-10, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler, task-scheduler

Where are scheduled tasks stored in an offline Windows 10 image, as within an `install.wim`, I noticed there are no scheduled tasks within an index's:

- `.\Windows\Tasks`: [image: Screenshot1]
- `.\Windows\System32\Tasks`: [image: Screenshot2]
- `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Schedule\TaskCache`: 
   *(shown are the basic tasks windows needs to function I guess)* [image: Screenshot3]

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I believe they get added as the software that requires them is installed during the install process.

Comment: @LPChip Do you think there is a way to interrupt that process and prevent specific tasks from being installed? Maybe via DISM? thanks for the info

Comment: Find out what programs match what scheduled task, and change that these are not installed I guess...

Comment: @PolisP You can't "interrupt" a Windows install, but you can boot to the [`auditSystem`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/auditsystem) setup phase via an answer file [[`Unattend.xml`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/wsim/windows-system-image-manager-how-to-topics)]  _(or include the changes within the answer file)_ or from OOBE via [`Ctrl`+`Shift`+`F3`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/boot-windows-to-audit-mode-or-oobe) and make your changes there.