# Where are scheduled tasks stored in an offline Windows 10 partition/hard drive?

Tags: windows-10, windows-task-scheduler, offline-files

I found this similar question: [Where are scheduled tasks stored in an offline windows 10 image?](https://superuser.com/questions/1598058/where-are-scheduled-tasks-stored-in-an-offline-windows-10-image), which however is about finding the tasks in an image file of a Windows installation.

I am looking for a way to find the tasks (and possibly delete some of them) in an offline Windows partition, for example when connecting the Windows partition on an external hard drive via USB.

Answer (score 4):

Tasks from Task Scheduler as stored in `C:\Windows\System32\Tasks` and you would need to find this folder in the Offline Image.

Tasks are most easily edited in Task Scheduler (try from the Online operating system), but not as easily edited outside of Task Scheduler, and you may be able to simply delete tasks in the location above.

[image: Screenshot]

Are you able to start the Offline Image, as that would be the best way to change tasks if you can do this?